# Estado de botones con Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

Quisiera saber como en `Codeigniter` cambiar el estado de el boton de activar que sea de color verde, que cuando esté desactivado este de color rojo, pero cuando le doy a activar este de color verde.

Código del controlador:

```
if ($activos =='true'){
    $actinomtest ='Activar';
    $valoresacti ='1';
    $colorbtn = 'class="btn btn success';
}else{
    $actinomtest ='Desactivar';
    $valoresacti ='0';
}
```

Y en esta línea dentro del mismo Controlador llamó a esas variables:

```
foreach ($data as $row){
        $botones='<button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btnedit text-center" onclick="botontest('.$row->idTest.')">Editar</button>
                  <a class="btn btn-warning" href="#">Editar tabla</a>
                  <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm btnactest text-center" onclick="btnactivtest('.$row->idTest.', '. $valoresacti.', '.$colorbtn .')">'.$actinomtest.'</button>';
}
```

Comment: Porque no haces todo eso desde el front-end con un if sencillo, mandando los datos a la vista y verificando si el valoresacti es igual a 0 o 1 y con eso poner un botón u otro y pasa el idtest al view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existen varias formas de hacerlo. La más simple, para mi, seria guardar en la variable `$colorbtn` únicamente la clase que le da el color a tu botón. En tu caso serian la clase `btn-success` para el color verde y `btn-danger` para el rojo.

Tu codigo podria quedar de la siguiente manera:

```
if ($activos =='true'){

  // Guardamos la clase que da el color verde
  $colorbtn = 'btn-success';

  $actinomtest ='Activar';
  $valoresacti ='1';

}else{

  // Guardamos la clase que da el color rojo
  $colorbtn = 'btn-danger';

  $actinomtest ='Desactivar';
  $valoresacti ='0';      
}
```

Ahora concatenas la variable  `$colorbtn` dentro del *atributo class del botón* de esta manera: `<button class="btn '.$colorbtn.' btn-sm btnactest text-center"'`...

El código completo quedaría así:

```
 foreach ($data as $row){
    $botones='<button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btnedit text-center" onclick="botontest('.$row->idTest.')">Editar</button>
              <a class="btn btn-warning" href="#">Editar tabla</a>
              <button class="btn '.$colorbtn.' btn-sm btnactest text-center" onclick="btnactivtest('.$row->idTest.', '. $valoresacti.', '.$colorbtn .')">'.$actinomtest.'</button>';
```

}

Aquí un enlace a la documentación de bootstrap 4 sobre los botones: [Botones en bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/buttons/)

Comment: Funcionó correctamente, muchas gracias la verdad.

Comment: @Pag si funcionó correctamente, no te olvides de marcar la respuesta como aceptada pulsando en la marca que aparece en la parte superior izquierda. Saludos